# Difference between pushing a docker image and installing helm image

Tags: docker, dockerfile, kubernetes-helm

I need to learn a CI pipeline in which there is a step for building and pushing an image using a Dockerfile and another step for creating a helm chart image in which there is a definition of the image created by the docker file. After that, there's a CD pipeline in which there's an installation of what was created by the helm chart only.

What is the difference between the image created directly by a Dockerfile and the one which is created by the helm chart? Why isn't the Docker image enough?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. Helm is a package manager, it uses Docker images as part of charts.

Comment: Helm charts have configs for Kubernetes and it uses Docker images which are built from Dockerfile.

Comment: @Maroun but eventually you're using the docker image, so what does the helm chart gives you that the docker file itself and the image doesn't have without?

Comment: You cannot "deploy" an image directly to Kubernetes. You need to use Kubernetes resources (ReplicaSets, Services ...) That is what Helm is for, to manage (version, install, upgrade, remove, ...) Kubernetes applications.

Comment: @YonatanNir Consider, as an example, installation of DataDog agents to your K8s cluster. If you want to manage by yourself, you'll need to manually create and configure many resources: daemonsets, serviceaccount, clusterrole, clusterrolebinding, secrets, and probably more resources. Using a package manager like Helm, does everything for you. But eventually, some resources will need to run a container - you provide the image in the chart.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Amount to effort**

To deploy a service on Kubernetes using docker image you need to manually create various configuration files like `deployment.yaml`. Such files keep on increasing as you have more and more services added to your environment.

In the Helm chart, we can provide a list of all services that we wish to deploy in `requirements.yaml` file and Helm will ensure that all those services get deployed to the target environment using `deployment.yaml`, `service.yaml` & `values.yaml` files.

**Configurations to maintain**

Also adding configuration like routing, config maps, secrets, etc becomes manually and requires configuration over-&-above your service deployment.

For example, if you want to add an Nginx proxy to your environment, you need to separately deploy it using the Nginx image and all the proxy configurations for your functional services.

But with Helm charts, this can be achieved by configuring just one file within your Helm chart: `ingress.yaml`

**Flexibility**

Using docker images, we need to provide configurations for each environment where we want to deploy our services.

But using the Helm chart, we can just override the properties of the existing helm chart using the environment-specific `values.yaml` file. This becomes even easier using tools like `ArgoCD`.

**Code-Snippet:**

Below is one example of `deployment.yaml` file that we need to create if we want to deploy one service using docker-image.

Inline, I have also described how you could alternatively populate a generic `deployment.yaml` template in Helm repository using different files like `requirements.yaml` and `Values.yaml`

**deployment.yaml for one service**

```
crazy-project/charts/accounts/templates/deployment.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: accounts
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
     matchLabels:
       app.kubernetes.io/name: accounts
       app.kubernetes.io/instance: crazy-project
  template:
     metadata:
       labels:
         app.kubernetes.io/name: accounts
         app.kubernetes.io/instance: crazy-project
     spec:
       serviceAccountName: default
       automountServiceAccountToken: true
       imagePullSecrets:
         - name: regcred
       containers:
       - image: "image.registry.host/.../accounts:1.2144.0"   <-- This version can be fetched from 'requirements.yaml'
         name: accounts
         env:      <-- All the environment variables can be fetched from 'Values.yaml'
         - name: CLUSTERNAME
           value: "com.company.cloud"
         - name: DB_URI
           value: "mongodb://connection-string&replicaSet=rs1"
         imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
         volumeMounts:
         - name: secretfiles
           mountPath: "/etc/secretFromfiles"
           readOnly: true
         - name: secret-files
           mountPath: "/etc/secretFromfiles"
           readOnly: true
         ports:
         - name: HTTP
           containerPort: 9586
           protocol: TCP
         resources:
           requests:
             memory: 450Mi
             cpu: 250m
           limits:
             memory: 800Mi
             cpu: 1
       volumes:
       - name: secretFromfiles
         secret:
           secretName: secret-from-files
       - name: secretFromValue
         secret:
           secretName: secret-data-vault
           optional: true
           items:...
```

Your `deployment.yaml` in Helm chart could be a generic template(code-snippet below) where the details are populated using `values.yaml` file.

```
env:
{{- range $key, $value := .Values.global.envVariable.common }}
    - name: {{ $key }}
      value: {{ $value  | quote }}
    {{- end }}
```

Your `Values.yaml` would look like this:

```
accounts:
  imagePullSecrets:
    - name: regcred
  envVariable:
    service:
      vars:
        spring_data_mongodb_database: accounts_db
        spring_product_name: crazy-project
        ...
```

Your `requirements.yaml` would be like below. 'dependencies' are the services that you wish to deploy.

```
dependencies:
  - name: accounts
    repository: "<your repo>"
    version: "= 1.2144.0"
  - name: rollover
    repository: "<your repo>"
    version: "= 1.2140.0"
```

The following diagram will help you visualize what I have mentioned above:

[image: Docker image v/S Helm chart]

Comment: So you're saying that in order to configure a docker image without a helm chart, you need to configure the same files like a chart has in its templates, only that a chart makes it simpler with the values file and the option to generate it with inline code, but will ultimately have the same files with the same content after its generated?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

These links should help you for understanding deployment using Docker Images: [Deploy to Kubernetes](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/kube-deploy/) and [Building and deploying a Docker image to a Kubernetes cluster](https://www.bluematador.com/blog/building-and-deploying-to-kubernetes).

And this link should help you understand deployment using Helm charts: [Helm Charts: making it simple to package and deploy common applications on Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2016/10/helm-charts-making-it-simple-to-package-and-deploy-apps-on-kubernetes/)